# How to delete the item selected in a Spinner on button click when the items are listed in strings.xml and not as static in Android Studio?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, spinner

I am facing a problem in deleting an item that is selected in a spinner. The thing is I've declared the array list inside strings like given below. The thing is when I select an item from the spinner and press the button,say delete button, the item should get deleted from the array list and should not show in the spinner dropdown, when I use that spinner again. I went through several examples, but in all those, the items are declared as static inside main activity itself, but I've declared them inside strings. Another thing is I have the button click event inside a FRAGMENT. It would be a great help if somebody help me with a code. Sorry if I am wrong with any terms. Thanks in advance.

`<string name="relation_spinner">Relation</string>
    <string-array name="relation_array">
        <item>--Select--</item>
        <item>Father</item>
        <item>Mother</item>
        <item>Son</item>
        <item>Daughter</item>
        <item>Brother</item>
        <item>Sister</item>
    </string-array>`

Comment: Is there nobody to help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself!
We should actually remove it via adapter.
The code goes below:

```
if (selectedText.equals("Father")) {
                    yourAdapter.remove(selectedText);
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

And/or if you would like to specify for multiple items, you can do this way:

```
if (selectedText.equals("Father") || selectedText.equals("Mother")) {
                    yourAdapter.remove(selectedText);
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Comment: maybe if you shared some code at first somebody could have a look. no one can assume what your code is and write an answer based on the assumption.

Comment: That is why I had briefed my problem under my question. But did not get any help. Might be I should've done like you say now. I thought I would get some help based on my description of the question. Anyway thanks for the comment Yazan.